# Importing CSV with a json array of strings in one of the column

Tags: postgresql, json, csv

The columns of the CSV are of the format `text` (can include empty lines), `date` and a JSON array of strings (something like `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I've been trying to copy that CSV to a PostgreSQL table (using `psycopg2`'s `copy_expert`, which simply executes the given SQL `COPY` command, if that matters)

Table is created with

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    rubrics jsonb[] NOT NULL
);
```

and the copy command is

```
COPY posts(text, created_date, rubrics)
FROM STDIN
WITH CSV HEADER
```

where `STDIN` is the CSV file.

The error I get is

```
malformed array literal: "['a', 'b', 'c']"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
CONTEXT:  COPY posts, line 15, column rubrics: "['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

I've tried all 4 JSON-related data types (`json` and `jsonb` with and without `[]` or `[3]`), including square brackets produces the error above, while omitting them (`rubrics jsonb NOT NULL` when creating) gives a new one:

```
invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ['...
COPY posts, line 15, column rubrics: "['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

Do I have any recourse besides manually fixing the .csv to use `{}` instead of `[]` before copying it? It feels like I do, yet I haven't really been able to found anything besides a couple somewhat, but not fully relevant questions.

## Update regarding the comments

I've changed the table creation to

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    rubrics jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

and left a single entry in the CSV to test, so it looks like this

```
text,created_date,rubrics
"Lorem

Ipsum

Test",2019-07-25 12:42:13,'["f", "o", "o"]'
```

### Things I've tried and errors I got

Using the CSV as is:

```
 extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY posts, line 6: ""Lorem

Ipsum

Test",2019-07-25 12:42:13,'["f", "o", "o"]'"
```

An additional pair of `""` around the array (`"'["f", "o", "o"]'"`)

```
 invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: '...
COPY posts, line 6, column rubrics: "'[f, o, o]'"
```

No quotes at all (just the `["f", "o", "o"]`)

```
extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY posts, line 6: ""Lorem

Ipsum

Test",2019-07-25 12:42:13,["f", "o", "o"]"
```

Double quotes instead of single quotes (`"["f", "o", "o"]"`)

```
invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "f" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: [f...
COPY posts, line 6, column rubrics: "[f, o, o]"
```

Double quotes outside, single quotes inside (`"['f', 'o', 'o']"`)

```
invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ['...
COPY posts, line 6, column rubrics: "['f', 'o', 'o']"
```

Could it be an issue with the Python library I'm using after all?

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c']` is not valid JSON, because strings must be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want `rubrics jsonb[]` and not `rubrics jsonb`?

Comment: @DanielVérité My bad, it's `"['a','b','c']"` if I view the CSV through a text editor (so one entry is `"Lorem Ipsum",2019-07-25 12:42:13,"['a', 'b', 'c']"`), I just had the file open in Excel

Comment: @mustaccio Neither seems to work, with different error messages

Comment: @bqback: the double quotes around the value are part of the CSV encapsulation, not of the JSON format. The value that needs to go into your column is still `['a', 'b', 'c']` and it's not a valid JSON or a valid array of JSON. Any JSON parser will reject that.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=679de16e119f46124cdcecfa9f6d1bfa

Comment: It's not clear what you want to store: a Postgres array of JSON string values, or a JSON array of strings. And if the former, then why do you need JSON strings specifically, instead of proper SQL strings.

Comment: @mustaccio The JSON array of strings is how it's stored in CSV, I could frankly go with either -- no combination of field types and characters around and in the array 
I've been able to get dbfiddle to work with data fairly similar to source https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8fc24a26bab90c8aef71e9e080502540, but trying to carry anything over to the actual .csv file and running the script produces a variety of errors (depending on what I change), I'll update the post

Comment: @DanielVérité See update, I've tried some configurations of quotes (including stuff that worked in the dbfiddle example I've posted), without much success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a layer of encapsulation with a [standardized syntax](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/) that the JSON field in your input must respect.

CSV is another layer of encapsulation that applies on top, with a syntax that is more of less [standardized in rfc 4180](https://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc?rfc=4180). As mentioned in the RFC, programs that read or write CSV do not always conform strictly to all these rules, but concerning the quoting rules, Postgres is conformant.

JSON uses double quotes around string literals, so all the attempts in the question to use single quotes around strings are invalid for the JSON parser

CSV requires that double quotes are doubled, see rules #5 and  #7 of rfc 4180, so all attempts to use double quotes in JSON without doubling them for CSV or without enclosing the entire field in double quotes are invalid for the CSV parser.

> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote

Your example slightly edited to conform to both CSV and JSON does work:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    rubrics jsonb NOT NULL
);

COPY posts(text, created_date, rubrics)
FROM STDIN WITH CSV;
foo,2022-05-17,"[""a"", ""b"", ""c""]"
\.

select * from posts;
 id | text |    created_date     |     rubrics     
----+------+---------------------+-----------------
  1 | foo  | 2022-05-17 00:00:00 | ["a", "b", "c"]
```

If you wanted a Postgres array of JSON objects in `rubrics`, that would be more complicated, as expressing the Postgres array as text requires another layer of encapsulation with its [own syntax rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO), so the production of valid data to import with COPY would have to do

JSON quoting -> postgres array quoting -> CSV quoting

But as seen in your example, it seems that you don't need a Postgres array of JSON objects as a column, but rather a single JSON value that contains a JSON array.

Comment: Thank you!! Made a quick `re.sub` and it worked!